# Dynamic routing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm working in an app with the following route definition.

```
get 'list/:city(/:zone)(/:district)'
```

It works perfectly when I want to catch URL like

```
/list/milan
/list/milan/milan-ovest
/list/milan/milan-ovest/brera
```

Now, we are moving to some pretty URL where at the end we need to place a pretty name. Something like this

```
 /list/milan/renting-apartment-in-milan
 /list/milan/milan-ovest/renting-apartment-in-milan-center
 /list/milan/milan-ovest/brera/renting-apartment-in-brera
```

I know about wild card, but I wasn't able to find a working solution. Actually the additional element could be ignored, meaning it doesn't offer any useful information.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can always stub in a glob-style path:

```
get 'list/*path'
```

That will capture an arbitrary number of elements after that point and provide them to you as `params[:path]` which will be an array.

The down-side of this is they won't be broken out in advance, but you can always take care of that through assignment:

```
city, zone, district, *extra = params[:path]
```